# How to return the list of objects and their count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, laravel

I want to replace the COUNT(ID) with the list of objects

i want to return an array containing the list of objects instead of returning

their count

my code:

```
$data['myresponse'] = DB::table("products")
            ->where('id_advisor',$advisor->id)->where('deleted_at', NULL)
            ->where('created_at',">=", $start)->where('created_at',"<=", $end)
            ->select(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) as date,COUNT(id) objects"))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'))
            ->get();
```

the response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "myresponse": [
            {
                "date": "2020-07-03",
                "objects": 2
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-07-05",
                "objects": 4
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-07-08",
                "objects": 8
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-07-09",
                "objects": 17
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

what i need is to return something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5gjU.png)

Comment: Question not clear. Please rephrase.

Comment: What is "objects"?

Comment: it is the number of items, i've changed it in the image that i've just added, 
i want to return the counted elements in another array with a specific key
forget about the key 'objects',i've changed it tou 'count' and i want 'objects' to contain the counted items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it from the other side. Select your objects and put them into the date buckets.

Laravel can help you out of the box grouping it per attribute. You'll only need to map it to the desired struct.

```
$products = DB::table("products")
    ->where('id_advisor',$advisor->id)->where('deleted_at', NULL)
    ->where('created_at',">=", $start)->where('created_at',"<=", $end)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('created_at');
```

**Original bits of code example **
Below is some (pseudo) code as an example over the reverse approach.

```php
$products = DB::table("products")
    ->where('id_advisor',$advisor->id)->where('deleted_at', NULL)
    ->where('created_at',">=", $start)->where('created_at',"<=", $end)
    ->get();
    
$buckets = $products->map(
  function($product) { 
    return $product->created_at; 
  }
)->unique();

$result = $buckets->map(function ($bucket) use ($products) {
    return [
      'date' => $bucket, 
      'products' => $products->filter(
        function($product) use ($bucket) { 
          return $product->created_at === $bucket;
        }
      )
    ];
});

dd($results);
```

Dump result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1050
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "date" => "2020-07-03"
      "products" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1048
        #items: array:1 [
          0 => array:2 [
            "date" => "2020-07-03"
            "id" => 1
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "date" => "2020-07-04"
      "products" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1047
        #items: array:2 [
          1 => array:2 [
            "date" => "2020-07-04"
            "id" => 2
          ]
          2 => array:2 [
            "date" => "2020-07-04"
            "id" => 3
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
      "date" => "2020-07-05"
      "products" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1045
        #items: array:1 [
          3 => array:2 [
            "date" => "2020-07-05"
            "id" => 4
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data['myresponse'] = DB::table("products")
            ->where('id_advisor',$advisor->id)->where('deleted_at', NULL)
            ->where('created_at',">=", $start)->where('created_at',"<=", $end)
            ->select(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) as date, DB::raw('count(*) as objects'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)')) // or ->groupBy('date')
            ->get();
```